# Field Types in Solr

Tags: solr

I had indexed data into `Solr` and add data into `"name","features"` field.

So, when I get data using java code I use `"getFieldValue("name")"` it returns the name into java variable.

When I use java code to get `"name"` values, I got null values.

When I look into Solr Admin Page: I had seen

`"Features"` field in Solr has properties `"Indexed, Tokenized, Stored, Multivalued".`

How can I get the values of Features into variables and print that.

Kindly ask me to further clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that `getFieldValue()` returns a Collection for multi-valued fields but you are expecting a String.

It may help if you can post the full code snippet you are using.